# ¿Como pintar una celda de acuerdo a una condición en C# epplus?

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

Tengo 2 consulta y son las siguientes

1.Quiero validar si la celda contiene valores menores a 9.00 que la pinte de amarillo.

2.Cuando se almacenan los valores en las celdas de excel desde c# .net epplus las celdas me dan una advertencia `"the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe"`.

El valor de las celdas es un decimal.

Y este es la línea de codigo que llena las celdas en el excel.

```
ws.Cells[i + 7, j + 1].Value = data.Rows[i][j].ToString();
```

---

```
public JsonResult ExportarResumenHoras()
        {
            DataTable data = GestionResumenHoras.Instancia.ListaResumenHoras();


            ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Detalle(Semana)");

            //Carga las columnas
            for (int c = 0; c < data.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                ws.Cells[6,c+1].Value = data.Columns[c];
            }


            //Carga los valores de acuerdo a la fecha registrada 
            if (data != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < data.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {

                        ws.Cells[i + 7, j + 1].Value = data.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();



            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            pkg.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Session["archivoResumenHoras"] = bytes;
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este solucion te requiere importar estas librarias:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.Drawing;
```

La advertencia `"the number in this cell is..."` aparece porque usa `.ToString()`. Esta significa que le dice a Excel para almacenar los numeros en el fomato de text.

Puede simplemente quitar el `.ToString()` y la advertencia desaparecerá.

Y para pintar las celdas con colores, puede probar esto:

```
Color colorDeCelda = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FCE811");


//Carga los valores de acuerdo a la fecha registrada 
if (data != null)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data.Columns.Count; j++)
        {

            ws.Cells[i + 7, j + 1].Value = data.Rows[i][j];

            // Pintar la celda si valor < 9.00
            if( j >= 2){
                if( data.Rows[i][j] != DBNull.Value){
                    if (Convert.ToDouble(data.Rows[i][j]) < 9.00)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i + 7, j + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        ws.Cells[i + 7, j + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colorDeCelda);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estimado en la condición if me muestra un error que dice lo siguiente "operator < cannot be applied to operand of type 'object' and 'double'"

Comment: No funciona usando decimal.parse ni tampoco Convert.ToDouble

Comment: Añade un if para convertir solo las columnas de numeros. Por favor pruebalo de nuevo.

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: No se puede convertir un objeto DBNull en otros tipos.

Comment: He editado de nuevo.

Comment: Ahora si funciono, gracias